# Not receiving the communication from Openfire Xmpp while connecting throw stropes.js

Tags: openfire, strophe, punjab

I am trying to create a client chat. I could able to to see the log of punjab server as Sending - Receiving. But  never showing as **Strophes Connected**
Did the following setup

1)Setup an Xmpp server

wget -O openfire.deb http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire_3.9.3_all.deb
and completed the setup as described in
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-openfire-xmpp-server-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps
 Now the openfire is accessble at *****xmppserver.com

2)setup Punjab Bosh Server in the same server 
By downloading from the github

https://github.com/twonds/punjab/blob/master/INSTALL.txt

and started running by twistd -ny punjab.tac

in `etc/hosts` added as

```
127.0.0.1 *****xmppserver.com
```

3) Finally downloaded latest strophes.js and edited basic.js

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://*****xmppserver.com:5280/http-bind';
```

The output is showing as connecting and never goes to connected!!

```
function onConnect(status) {
        console.log(status);
        if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
            log('Strophe is connecting.');
        } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
            log('Strophe failed to connect.');
            $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
        } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
            log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
        } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
            log('Strophe is disconnected.');
            $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
        } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            log('Strophe is connected.');
            log('Send a message to ' + connection.jid +
            ' to talk to me.');

            connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null,  null);
            connection.send($pres().tree());
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Never used Punjab, but Openfire has its own built in BOSH conn manager. You can enable it on Openfire's admin panel: Server > Server Settings > HTTP Binding. Try with it at your 'http://*****xmppserver.com:7070/http-bind/'.

Comment: tried that too but got the following error              XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://******xmppserver:7070/http-bind.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Which server are you running at localhost? If Apache then add proxy something like `ProxyPass /http-bind http://******xmppserver:7070/http-bind` and `ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://******xmppserver:7070/http-bind`.

Comment: Then your bosh url will be `http://localhost/http-bind/`, and note the extra "/" at the end of http-bind. It is crucial for Strophe.

Comment: the extra "/" was the issue. with 7070 every thing works fine :)  and  didnt add any ProxyPass to apache server, my basic doubt is that for y we place bosh punjab in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the Openfire's built in BOSH http connection manager. Enable it on Openfire's admin panel:
 *Server > Server Settings > HTTP Binding*, then the BOSH URL should be like

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://*****xmppserver.com:7070/http-bind/';
```

Putting a `/` at the end of `/http-bind` is crucial for Strophe.

Comment: can u pls change it to 7070 instead of 5280 i tried with 5280 but didn't get. 7070 is working fine